# Is it possible to specify how slick translate column?

Tags: slick

I need to try the program on different databases.
However for data type like "String", different databases has its own data type.
If I define a table in slick like this:

```
class Table_x(tag:Tag) extends Table[someclass](tag,"somename"){
  import Mappers._

  def url = column[String]("url",O.NotNull,O.DBType("TEXT"))
  def ref = column[Option[String]]("ref",O.DBType("TEXT"))
  ....
}
```

In postgresql, I want column `url` to be translated to `TEXT`. In hsqldb, I want it to be `VARCHAR`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Doesn't Slick do that automatically?

Comment: @Niels ,Slick automatically translate it to VARCHAR. However I need TEXT for postgresql. VARCHAR is too "short" in postgresql.

Comment: This may solve this: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1065   Part of Slick 3.0. You can provide a O.Length and Slick chooses an appropriate type for your backend.